# How to call didDeselectRowAt of tableView in a collectionView

Tags: uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview

I have a **collectionView** and a **tableView**. When I toggle a cell on tableView, it adds/removes that cell to collectionView. And remove a cell from collectionView when I click on it. I want to call didDeselctRowAt of tableView when clicking on cells of collectionView.

```
tableView(tableView, didDeselectRowAt: indexPath) // in collectionView
```

The above method is working. However, When I click tableView' cell again this method calls again. Is there any property like

```
cell.isDidDeselect = true // cell of tableView
```

To prevent calling again it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moved solution from question to answer:

> **Update and Answer**
>
> I found answer:
>
> use
>
> ```
> tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
> tableView.delegate?.tableView!(tableView, didDeselectRowAt: indexPath)
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```
> tableView(tableView, didDeselectRowAt: indexPath)
> ```